# Deserialize json into python like Dictionary with C#

Tags: c#

I need to write a dynamically typed system in a statically typed language using the `System.Text.Json` lib in .net core 3.1.  What I need is to deserialize files into a Python like dict. I have to use C# for this because we can't get python to authenticate against our systems correctly. And C# is our default lang, so...

In the real world, these documents are in CosmosDB. This program takes in a configuration file that points to specific fields in document structures and it has to inspect those fields, maybe update them, then write the result back to the CosmosDB. Currently, I'm building a system that points to the specific field.  Since the system has no clue what the structure of the doc is that it's getting back from the cosmos, it can't use formal models. I am currently working on the system that inspects or updates the fields using static files in the test suite.  I'll worry about cosmos DB when this is finished.

Take this file for example:

```
{
  "azureSql": {
    "databaseName": "ordersdb",
    "tables": [
      {
        "tableName": "mytable",
        "columnNames": [
          "column1",
          "column2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "cosmosDb": {
    "databaseName": "CosmosDb",
    "collections": [
      {
        "collectionName": "TestCollection",
        "fieldNames": [
          "MyStatus.json.path.to.field"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

files like this get read in.  The input can be virtually any type of legit json.  I need to put that into a Dictionary that I can access similar to Python `mydict["cosmosDb"]["collections"][0]["fieldNames"]`

The line:

```
_entities = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(jsonString);
```

doesn't work because it only serializes the first level. The rest are json entry types.

I found this [C# way to mimic Python Dictionary Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381359/c-sharp-way-to-mimic-python-dictionary-syntax)

and its close, but it only supports string and doesn't work in the `Deserialize` method.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: why dont you use dynamic? `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString)`

Comment: Did you tried `_entities = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(jsonString);` ? Why don't you use it without the generic type

Comment: I looked at ExpandoObject and man what a pain.  Since i don't know what the name of the field is, i have to constantly loop the keys of the dictionary on each level to find the right key.  I really don't like that idea because this is a batch job.  I havn't found a way to directly access the keys in an expando like i can in python.

Comment: @scphantm Did you manage to solve this? We're stuck on the exact same problem. Please advise or point us to the answer if possible.

Comment: We ended up using dynamic and ExpandoObject.  its a royal pain but it can be done.  things like `getKeys` is really rough.  There are tutorials out there about using dynamic.  but the core problem of trying to do dynamic typing in a static language just balloons the code.  expect to write TONS of boiler plate code to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use dynamic

```
var entities = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<dynamic>(jsonString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the following classes structure work?

```
    public class Rootobject
    {
        public Azuresql azureSql { get; set; }
        public Cosmosdb cosmosDb { get; set; }
    }

    public class Azuresql
    {
        public string databaseName { get; set; }
        public List<Table> tables { get; set; }
    }

    public class Table
    {
        public string tableName { get; set; }
        public List<string> columnNames { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cosmosdb
    {
        public string databaseName { get; set; }
        public List<Collection> collections { get; set; }
    }

    public class Collection
    {
        public string collectionName { get; set; }
        public List<string> fieldNames { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit:
This works:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

var result = JObject.Parse(jsonFile);
var detail = result["cosmosDb"]["collections"][0]["collectionName"];
```

Comment: the structure can be any json.  go on google and randomly pick a json file, this routine needs to be able to read it and address it.